# bibliography using babelbib

Tags: bibliographies, babel

I'm trying to make the bibliography in my document using babelbib since my document haw 2 languages. But then i ask to print it, the whole bibliography is in one language.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb} \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{ucs} \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel} \usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage{babelbib} 

\begin{document} the thing is that \cite{text1}, but it's also
\cite{text2}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite} \bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

And my bib file:

```
@book{text1,
    title     = "geometria",
    author   = "Petrou",
    year      = "2015",
    language = {italian},
    langid = {italian},
    hyphenation="italian"
}

@book{text2,
  title={The book},
  author={Conway},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Springer},
  language = {english},
  langid = {english},
  hyphenation = "english"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  `babelbib` only works with specific bibliographystyles `babplain` etc.  I don't think `apacite` provides a relevant interface.